# Chaging the datatypes of specific column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem wherein I need to change the datatype of ONLY some of the column of my dataframe headers.

My Header are as per below:

> 'Name'    'Manager'   'Review Manager'
>   '3-Feb-20'    '10-Feb-20' '17-Feb-20' '24-Feb-20' '2-Mar-20'  '9-Mar-20'  '16-Mar-20' '23-Mar-20' '30-Mar-20'

I only want to change the datatype of the header values which are appearing as dates: 
*'3-Feb-20' '10-Feb-20' '17-Feb-20' '24-Feb-20' '2-Mar-20'  '9-Mar-20'  '16-Mar-20' '23-Mar-20' '30-Mar-20'*

**I don't want to change the header of 1 - 3 columns only from 4th to the last column.**

What I have tried is as per below:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Tracker.xlsx', skiprows=range(1,6), sheet_name='Status', header=[1])
```

I understand that I can change the datatype of the column as:

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(datatype)
```

1. but how do I change the datatype of the column which are themselves 'dates'? How do I refer to the date columns?
2. Also how do I find out the last column in the dataframe? I want to change the datatypes of all the date columns from 4th to the last column. In openpyxl we can use

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Tracker.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active 
    column = ws.max_column
    row = ws.max_row
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly.
To change the datatype to datetime using the pd.to_datetime() function

Comment: Fetch date columns using condition if number in column name ? `date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if any(char.isdigit() for char in col)]`

Answer (score 0):

To change the column name date type using `df.columns.astype(newtype)`. See example below.

In this excel file, the first 2 column names are strings and the next 4 column names are date values

```
df = pd.read_excel('text.xlsx')
print([(col, type(col)) for col in df.columns])
```

Output:

```
[('col0', <class 'str'>), ('col1', <class 'str'>), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 9, 0, 0), <class 'datetime.datetime'>), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 10, 0, 0), <class 'datetime.datetime'>), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 0, 0), <class 'datetime.datetime'>), (datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 13, 0, 0), <class 'datetime.datetime'>)]
```

Converting the data type of the column names to `str`

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
print([(col, type(col)) for col in df.columns])
```

Output:

```
[('col0', <class 'str'>), ('col1', <class 'str'>), ('2017-07-09 00:00:00', <class 'str'>), ('2017-07-10 00:00:00', <class 'str'>), ('2017-07-11 00:00:00', <class 'str'>), ('2017-07-13 00:00:00', <class 'str'>)]
```

You can see that all column names, data types are now `str`